# Map parameter C++

Tags: c++, maps

I am having an issue of putting a Boolean value in the maps as the 3rd parameter. Something like the following :

```
int value;
std::map<String str, int x, bool bl>
```

where bool returns false if x>value else true.

All I see in the map examples is that I can add the compare object parameters which compares the key value of the map and returns the result accordingly.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense. But could this be an [*X-Y problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Instead of stepping into the solution space, can you explain what is the actual problem (you want to solve)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it, here are two:

1:

```
std::map< std::string, std::pair<int,bool> > mymap;
mymap["xyz"].first = someValue;
mymap["xyz"].second = someValue > value;
```

2:

```
struct MapElement
{
    int x;
    bool bl;
};

std::map< std::string, MapElement > mymap;
mymap["xyz"].x = someValue;
mymap["xyz"].bl = someValue > value;
```

The map type does not have to specify the member (like `int x`) you need to only specify a type that has x and bl as member (example 2).

Comment: The second suggestion is excellent for his purposes: he could have a member function that returns true if the value `x` is greater than some arbitrary `value` constant he's talking about.

Comment: I took 2nd Approach for my problem, and it works accordingly!Thank you.